# Exterior square of $\operatorname{Sp}(4,\mathbb{C})$ is isomorphic to $\operatorname{SO}(5,\mathbb{C})$

Tags: rt.representation-theory, lie-groups

I am studying exceptional isomorphisms recently, which arise due to the coincidence in Dynkin diagram.

I saw two forms of expressing the exceptional isomorphisms, one is isomorphisms between the spin group and the corresponding group, established by spin or half-spin representations; the other is isomorphism from symmetric squares, exterior squares or tensor squares of the relevant group to the special orthogonal group. But in this case, I don't know how to construct the induced symmetric bilinear form on the vector space. And in the case ${\bigwedge}^2\operatorname{Sp}(4,\mathbb{C})\cong \operatorname{SO}(5,\mathbb{C})$, I think the dimension of exterior square of a 4-dimensional vector space is 6, and I am not clear how it gets mapped into $\operatorname{SO}(5)$.

Comment: As written, your equation doesn't make sense; one cannot take the exterior square of a group, and I think you don't mean to take the exterior square of the Lie algebra.  I suspect what you mean is that $G = \operatorname{Sp}(4, \mathbb C)$ is isomorphic to $\operatorname{Spin}(5, \mathbb C)$—or you could say that it has a mapping onto $H = \operatorname{SO}(5, \mathbb C)$ that annihilates the centre.  ($G$ and $H$ are *not* isomorphic.)  […](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/428983/exterior-square-of-sp4-mathbbc-is-isomorphic-to-so5-mathbbc#comment1103463_428983)

Comment: […](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/428983/exterior-square-of-sp4-mathbbc-is-isomorphic-to-so5-mathbbc#comment1103462_428983) Then you try to show this using an isomorphism of ${\bigwedge}^2\mathbb C^4$ with $\mathbb C^5$ that intertwines the actions, but of course there isn't one, because ${\bigwedge}^2\mathbb C^4$ is 6D and $\mathbb C^5$ is 5D.  Instead one way to proceed is to consider the 5D representation ${\bigwedge}^2(\mathbb C^4)^*/\mathbb C\omega$, where $\omega$ is the symplectic form—which is preserved by $G$ by definition!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

$\DeclareMathOperator\SL{SL}\DeclareMathOperator\SO{SO}\DeclareMathOperator\Sp{Sp}\DeclareMathOperator\Ker{Ker}$Let's start with the double cover $\SL(4) \to \SO(6)$. Let $V$ be the standard $4$-dimensional representation of $\text{SL}(4)$, and let $\bigwedge^2 V$ be its tensor square.  We have a non-degenerate symmetric bilinear form $\bigwedge^2 V \times \bigwedge^2 V \to \bigwedge^4 V \cong \mathbb{C}$ by $\langle \alpha, \beta \rangle = \alpha \wedge \beta$. (This is symmetric because even degree wedges commute with each other.) So the action of $\SL(4)$ preserves this symmetric bilinear form, and we get a map $\SL(4) \to \SO(6)$. This can be checked to be a double cover (the kernel is $\pm \mathrm{Id}$ and a computation with Lie algebras checks that the map is surjective).

Now, let $\omega : V \times V \to \mathbb{C}$ be a symplectic form and let $\Sp(4)$ be the subgroup of $\SL(4)$ preserving this form. Then $\omega$ induces a linear map $L_{\omega} : \bigwedge^2 V \to \mathbb{C}$, and $\Sp(4)$ preserves the $5$-dimensional space $\Ker(L_{\omega})$ inside $\bigwedge^2 V$. So $\Sp(4)$ maps to $\SO(5)$, sitting inside $\SO(6)$, and this is again a double cover.

Comment: Most of this was in LSpice's comments, but I wanted to spell out where the symmetric bilinear form comes from, and at that point it seemed like it deserved to be an answer.

Comment: We also chose dual realisations: I chose a quotient of ${\bigwedge}^2(\mathbb C^4)^*$, and you chose a subobject of ${\bigwedge}^2\mathbb C^4$.  Anyway, as you say, it's certainly worth writing all these things down explicitly—it can be hard to find such "everyone knows" folklore expounded anywhere accessible.  My comments: [1](https://mathoverflow.net/posts/comments/1103462) [2](https://mathoverflow.net/posts/comments/1103463).